# Protected Route and React Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, react-router, react-context

I have a context (AuthContext) which lets me know whether the user is authenticated or not. I had also created a protected route which lets me log onto DashBoard if the user is authenticated otherwise redirects to login. I am however having a problem connecting those two so that it happens together.

ProtectedRoute.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext';

const ProtectedRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => {
        const { isAuthenticated } = this.context;

        return (
          <Route
            {...rest}
            render={(props) => {
              const { isAuthenticated } = this.context; //getting an error here
              if (isAuthenticated) {
                return <Component {...props} />;
              } else {
                return (
                  <Redirect
                    to={{
                      pathname: '/',
                      state: {
                        from: props.location,
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                );
              }
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

AuthContext.js

```
import React, { Component, createContext } from 'react';

export const AuthContext = createContext();

class AuthContextProvider extends Component {
  state = {
    isAuthenticated: false,
  };
  toggleAuth = () => {
    this.setState({ isAuthenticated: !this.state.isAuthenticated });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <AuthContext.Provider
        value={{ ...this.state, toggleAuth: this.toggleAuth }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}

export default AuthContextProvider;
```

Edited code (getting an error saying render is not a function)

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext'



const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => {

    return (
        <AuthContext.Consumer>
            {({context}) => (   
                <Route
                    {...rest}
                    render={(props) => {
                    const {isAuthenticated} = context;
                        if(isAuthenticated) {
                            return <Component {...props} />;
                        } else {
                            return (
                                <Redirect
                                to={{
                                    pathname: "/",
                                    state: {
                                        from: props.location
                                    }
                                }}
                                />
                            );
                         } 
                    }}
                />
            )};
        </AuthContext.Consumer>
    )
}

export default ProtectedRoute
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument provided to the context consumer function is the `value` prop in the corresponding provider.

```js
  return (
    <AuthContext.Consumer>
      {(context) => (
        <Route
          {...rest}
          render={(props) => {
            const { isAuthenticated } = context; // no `this`
            // ...
          }}
        />
      )}
    </AuthContext.Consumer>
  );
```

I noticed that in your original code there are some syntax errors:

- You need to enclose the body of the consumer function in braces if you're using `return`.
- Since the consumer function is a child of the consumer element, you need to provide a closing tag.

Comment: I am still getting an error saying render is not a function. Posted my edited code in the original post.

Comment: Can you add your exact error and any additional context to your question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62143174/on-successful-login-this-props-history-push-does-not-take-to-new-page-as-protec/62144096#62144096