# On successful login, this.props.history.push does not take to new page as ProtectedRoute is not successful

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

After I receive a 200 status code, I try to go to the dashboard page. However, it does not work as intended. I am using React Context and ProtectedRoute. When I get the successful response, I call the `login()` function and it makes `isAuthenticated` as true but still does not take me to the dashboard Page.

PS: I checked and saw that in my protected route, it goes to the second part and gets redirected to "/" and hence I am on the same page. Do not know why that is happening

Signin

```
import { AuthContext } from './AuthContext'

async handleSubmit(event) {

        //I send the request before this

            const status = await res.status
            const json = await res.json();
            if(status === 200) {
                const {login} = this.context;
                login();
                this.props.history.push('/dashBoard')
                console.log('done')
            } else {
                console.log('not done')
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error', error)
        }
    }
static contextType = AuthContext;

render() {
return ( 
<Container className="formlogin">
                <div>
                    <Form className = "signinform backg-sheet1" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div>
                            <h3 style = {{color: 'white', textAlign: 'center'}}> SIGN IN </h3>
                            <Form.Group controlId = "formBasicUsername">
                                <Form.Label style = {{color: 'white'}}>Username</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control required name = "username" type = "text" placeholder = "Enter username" onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                            </Form.Group>


                            <Form.Group controlId = "formBasicPassword">
                                <Form.Label style = {{color: 'white'}}>Password</Form.Label>
                                <Form.Control required name = "password" type = "password" placeholder = "Enter password" onChange = {this.handleChange}/>
                            </Form.Group>


                            <div style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>
                                <Button variant="warning" type="submit">
                                    Submit
                                </Button>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </Container>
        );
    }
}

export default withRouter(SignIn);
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() { 
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
          <AuthProvider>
            <NavigationBar />
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path = '/'
                component = {LandingPage}
              />
              <Route exact path = '/register'
                component = {Register}
              />
              <ProtectedRoute exact path = '/dashBoard' 
                component = {dashBoard}
              />
            </Switch>
          </AuthProvider>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
}

export default App;
```

AuthProvider

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';

export const AuthContext = React.createContext();

class AuthProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        isAuthenticated: false
    }

    constructor() {
        super()
        this.login = this.login.bind(this)
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this)
    }

    login() {
        setTimeout(() => this.setState({ isAuthenticated: true }), 1000)
    }

    logout() {
        this.setState({ isAuthenticated: false })
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.state.isAuthenticated)
        return(
            <AuthContext.Provider value={{isAuthenticated: this.state.isAuthenticated, login: this.login, logout: this.logout}}>
            {this.props.children}
            </AuthContext.Provider>
        )
    }
}

const AuthConsumer = AuthContext.Consumer


export { AuthProvider, AuthConsumer }
```

ProtectedRoute

```
import React from 'react'
import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AuthConsumer } from './AuthContext'

const ProtectedRoute = ({component: Component, ...rest}) => (
        <AuthConsumer>
            {({ isAuthenticated }) => ( 
                <Route

                    render={(props) => 
                        isAuthenticated?<Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/" />
                    }
                    {...rest}
                />
            )}
        </AuthConsumer>
)

export default ProtectedRoute
```

LandingPage

```
import React from 'react';
import SignIn from './SignIn'
import NavigationBar from './NavigationBar'
import {Row} from 'react-bootstrap';
import './Styles.css'

class LandingPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                    <div className = "backg">
                        <div className = "backg-sheet">
                            <SignIn />
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

export default LandingPage
```

Comment: any error u r getting? ... how are u rendering signin? why signin is not in router? ... consolelog isAuthenticated and login inside signIn component..and share full code of signin .. .also put some console.log inside if(status===200)..

Comment: may be signin is not inside the <Authprovider> and therefore it cannot access the context? ... im just guessing ... please share more code, lets see

Comment: The console.log in (status===200) works and even everything before it and it gets printed successfully. I am not getting any error. Only the page does not get rerouted to dashboard but instead gets redirected to "/" according to the protectedrouter ternary condition. I tried changing the "/" to another url and it directed it there hence I know that is where the issue is.
Also I have added more code to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make few corrections and you will successfully get navigated to dashboard page.

1. Your handleSubmit is a normal function and you are losing the context of `this`. So make it an arrow function
2. Use event.preventDefault else browser will reload and you end up back to `/` page.

I have placed your code in the sandbox and made it work.

[image: Edit router auth issue fix]

**Code snippet**

```js
handleSubmit = async event => {
    try {
      event.preventDefault();
      //I send the request before this
      // console.log("this.context", this.context); //<---- prints successfully

      const status = 200; //await res.status;
      // const json = await res.json();
      if (status === 200) {
        const { login } = this.context;
        await login();
        console.log("this.context", this.context);
        this.props.history.push("/dashBoard");
        console.log("done");
      } else {
        console.log("not done");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error", error);
    }
  };
```

Comment: In the code in the sandbox, I have to click on submit twice to make it work. Like if you print ```console.log("this.context", this.context);``` after ```login()```, you will see that on the first submit, it stays false, but on the next one, it becomes true. That does not work in my case and it still does not go to dashboard. :(

Comment: hi - okay - yes, just make the login async and return a promise... in handleSubmit await the result. I have updated the answer as well as the codesandbox (use same link , refresh page) ..

Comment: It was still not working but then I removed the setTimeout in login() and it worked. I don't know why that was the case though. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement withRouter component in order for you have access with this.props.hostory... variable just like this below.

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router'; 


export default withRouter(Login);
```